# paste html into org mode

Tags: org-mode

Is there any easy way to copy/paste text from a browser window into an org file, automatically converting  links into [[][]] org-mode links? thanks!

Comment: You could save HTML and convert to org with `pandoc`.

Comment: Isn't there some type of insert link command, with a minibuffer read prompt, where you can simply yank the link from kill-ring and paste it into the minibuffer and then hit return?

Comment: @lawlist: there is; but the question is about the case where there is a large piece of text with multiple links... I'll check out `pandoc`, thanks!

Comment: Similar https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/12121/org-mode-parsing-rich-html-directly-when-pasting

Answer (score 10, accepted):

## Copying html in org format from `eww`

This requires emacs 24.4 or later.

1. Configure the `org-eww` module. It's not part of org, you'll have to pull the repo into some folder (`git clone https://orgmode.org/org-mode.git`) or manually copy the [file](http://orgmode.org/w/?p=org-mode.git;a=blob_plain;f=contrib/lisp/org-eww.el;hb=HEAD) into some package folder, although git is recommended as it helps you keep things up to date.
2. Then add the contribute folder into your path and say that org-eww is required. If you cloned from git, the `org-eww.el` file will be in `/path/where/you/cloned/org-mode/contrib/lisp/`.

   `(add-to-list 'load-path "/dir/path/containing/org-eww.el/")`

   `(require 'org-eww)`
3. Open a web-page in `eww` (eww is a browser in emacs, `M-x eww`). You can get emacs to open links in eww via: `(setq browse-url-browser-function 'eww-browse-url)`. This is useful in combination with helm-google + eww).
4. Select the region you want to copy from the html page and do `M-x org-eww-copy-for-org-mode`. If no region is selected, the whole webpage is copied (including links to images). As of now the `o` key is not bound to the `eww-mode-map`. For convenience, this command can be bound to that key in that mode map:

   `(define-key eww-mode-map (kbd "o") #'org-eww-copy-for-org-mode)`
5. Then use `C-y` to paste into your org mode file/buffer. With `iimage-mode` you can even see the images from the website and links are converted to the org-mode format.

Comment: Thanks! The `pandoc` tool suggested in comments is another solution -- for me it would be a bit easier to implement, but it is nice to have a method that does not rely upon tools outside of Emacs...

Comment: That seems promising. However the text formatting is still lost... For example *italics*, **bold** and `code`. Sometimes I just want to copy a part of the text instead of the whole web page, preserving the format. Is there any alternative to `pandoc` approach.

Comment: I might still prefer to use some external tools such as `Evernote` or `Quiver` if that's not possible.

Answer (score 5):

I wrote an add-on [Copy as Org-Mode](https://github.com/kuanyui/copy-as-org-mode) for Firefox which can do this in browser directly, it even can convert HTML tables into Org-mode format.
[image]

Answer (score 4):

late to the party, but as @xji said, `org-eww-copy-for-org-mode` doesn't preserve formatting, it only does links.

if you want to actually end up with org headings and preserved formatting, try https://github.com/alphapapa/org-web-tools.

From `eww`, hit `w` to copy URL of current page (or copy from another browser), then run `org-web-tools-read-url-as-org`.

further details are in the readme.

Comment: IIRC, they delegate to pandoc, which is one of the best pieces of software out there.