# html to orgmode via pandoc- get rid of all #+BEGIN_HTML blocks

Tags: org-mode, pandoc

i tried converting html webpages to org mode file using a simple pandoc command:

```
pandoc -o output.org R\ Seminar:\ Introduction\ to\ ggplot2.htm
```

this works quite well but im left with tons of html blocks that look like this

```
#+BEGIN_HTML
  <div class="rcode">
#+END_HTML

#+BEGIN_HTML
  <div class="source">
#+END_HTML

#+BEGIN_EXAMPLE
    #declare data and x and y aesthetics, but no shapes yet
    ggplot(data = Milk, aes(x=Time, y=protein))
#+END_EXAMPLE

#+BEGIN_HTML
  </div>
#+END_HTML

#+BEGIN_HTML
  </div>
#+END_HTML

#+BEGIN_HTML
  <div class="rimage default">
#+END_HTML
```

any clue how to get rid of these annoying #+BEGIN_HTML blocks during conversion?

Comment: Duplicate? https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/12121/org-mode-parsing-rich-html-directly-when-pasting If that doesn't answer your question, please explain why and provide an MWE.

Comment: thx but the same issues arise in that answer since it uses pandoc for converting. this still adds the #+BEGIN_HTML  <div class="rimage default"> blocks all over when pasting.i want to get rid of these blocks

Comment: You can probably use regexp-replace to remove it all: `(replace-regexp "#\\+BEGIN_HTML\\(?:.*\\|\n\\)*#\\+END_HTML" "")` but without all those divs, the output may not be exactly what you started with.

Comment: thx. i tried evaling the above code snippet in the org buffer but i get a debugging error: https://paste.xinu.at/oqJs/. any clue?

Comment: Hie, since I have this exact problem too, I bump up this question.
The code purposed in the comment of the question gives the same error than the one the author encountered.
And because of these #+BEGIN_HTML swarming everywhere in the file, the org file conversion is unusuable...
Thanks you.

Comment: im also still very interested in a solution for this.

Comment: This question was asked (by me) and answered on the pandoc mailing list. See https://groups.google.com/forum/m/?utm_medium=email&utm_source=footer#!msg/pandoc-discuss/GwVP6mu38ZE/1FkyuCmHGgAJ

Answer (score 3):

From the [solution linked to by ista](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/24676/html-to-orgmode-via-pandoc-get-rid-of-all-begin-html-blocks#comment55383_24676) ([direct link to the solution](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!msg/pandoc-discuss/GwVP6mu38ZE/s22pKJqOGgAJ)), you can create a pandoc filter, say in file `nodivs-filter.hs`

```
import Text.Pandoc.JSON

main = toJSONFilter nodivs
  where nodivs (Div _ bs) = bs
        nodivs b          = [b]
```

You then compile the filter with ghc: `ghc nodivs-filter.hs`. Finally, you use the filter when converting, as follows:

```
pandoc --filter ./nodivs-filter input-file.html -o output.org
```

In order to compile the pandoc filter, you need to have the relevant libraries. For instance, on Ubuntu, you'd need the `libghc-pandoc-types-dev` package (`sudo apt-get install libghc-pandoc-types-dev`). More generally, you could also try installing via `cabal` (`cabal install pandoc`).

#### To understand the haskell filter

The relevant hackage documentation is [here](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/pandoc-types-1.19/docs/Text-Pandoc-JSON.html) and [here](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/pandoc-types-1.19/docs/Text-Pandoc-Definition.html#t:Block).

Re-writing the program in long form, and adding comments (starting with `--` and hopefully useful for somebody not used to haskell):

```
import Text.Pandoc.JSON

main = toJSONFilter nodivs

-- Type signature (convert a block to a list of blocks)
nodivs :: Block -> [Block]
--- Case when our input block is a Div
-- Div constructors have the form 
--  Div Attr [Block] 
-- _ means we ignore the attribute (Attr)
nodivs (Div _ bs) = bs
--- Fall through (any other type of block)
-- bs (above) is a list of blocks, so to have consistent types
-- we must convert our fall though block into a one-member list of blocks
nodivs b          = [b]
```

## Some alternatives

These all come from [this thread](https://github.com/jgm/pandoc/issues/3771) on pandoc's github.

### Disable the `native_divs` extension

In your case:

```
pandoc -f html-native_divs -t org -o output.org R\ Seminar:\ Introduction\ to\ ggplot2.htm
```

(`-f html-native_divs` means from html, without native_divs)

### Use pandoc 2.0

AFAICT from the above-mentioned thread, the defaults will become slightly more convenient.

Answer (score 1):

You can replace those blocks like this:

```
(replace-regexp (rx (optional "\n")
                    "#+BEGIN_HTML"
                    (minimal-match (1+ anything))
                    "#+END_HTML"
                    (optional "\n"))
                "")
```

Answer (score 1):

**Try this**

1. Use pandoc to convert to HTML to LaTex.

   ```
   pandoc -o output.latex R\ Seminar:\ Introduction\ to\ ggplot2.htm
   ```
2. Use pandoc to convert LaTex to Org

   ```
   pandoc -o output.org output.latex
   ```

---

> **Tested using**
>   pandoc version: 1.19.2.1
>   Compiled with pandoc-types 1.17.0.4, texmath 0.9, skylighting 0.1.1.4

Comment: This actually works surprisingly well!